# Roll back laravel one time operations

Tags: php, laravel, database, package, jobs

I am using the package `https://github.com/TimoKoerber/laravel-one-time-operations` .
The package creates an operation that gets executed once. My question is:
Is there a way I can reverse/rollback the operation like we have in migrations?

I searched the github repo but did not find any feature like that

Comment: I don't think that you can revert the command/job, only DB [migration](https://github.com/TimoKoerber/laravel-one-time-operations/blob/main/database/migrations/2023_02_28_000000_create_one_time_operations_table.php). Create a issue on git and try to get more answers/ a new feature.